# I am trying to use php inside .html file with gulp-connect-php on windows

Tags: gulp-watch

I am new to gulp and trying to use php inside .html file with gulp-connect-php on windows.
The html file is included the code
 `<?php echo "test"; ?>`.
But, It does not appear "test" on the browser. So, could you tell me how to solve this problem?
The below is my gulpfile.js. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var browser = require("browser-sync");
var connect = require("gulp-connect-php");

gulp.task("server", function() {
    connect.server({
        bin:'c:/xampp/php/php.exe',
        ini:'c:/xampp/php/php.ini',
        port:3000,
        base:'./www'
    }, function(){
        browser({
        proxy:'localhost:3000'
        // server: {
        //     baseDir: "./"
        // }
    });
    });
});

gulp.task("reload", function() {
    browser.reload({stream:true});
});


gulp.task("default",['server'], function() {
    gulp.watch("./*.php",["reload"]);
});
```

Comment: I have already added the directive [AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html] to the php.ini . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
I added `router: '. /router.php'` parameter to connect.server({.
gulp-connect-php runs a php Built-in web server internally.
It can set the router script for the php Built-in web server by adding the router parameter.

Built-in web server:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

```
    connect.server({
        bin:'c:/xampp/php/php.exe',
        ini:'c:/xampp/php/php.ini',
        port:3000,
        base:'./www',
        router: './router.php'
    }, function(){
```

router.php

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];
if(preg_match("/\.html$/", $path)){
    chdir(dirname($path));
    return require($path);
}
return false;
?>
```